# Match the three columns in 2 annotation files and print those lines to a new output file

Tags: linux, stack

I have 2 files, file 1 and file 2 with the same column numbers. Column one has the chromosome number, column two has the promoter start site and column three has the promoter stop site.

I want to match both files, if a match to all the three columns in file 1 is found in file 2. I want to generate an output file showing the exact three columns with a fourth one. The fourth one would show a match with a score of 1 and a mismatch with a score of 0.

File 1:

```
chr1 899 1098
chr3 677 900
chr3 844 1045
```

File 2:

```
chr3 844 1045
chr1 899 1098
chr4 500 789
```

Output File:

```
chr1 899 1098  1
chr3 677 900   0
chr3 844 1045  1
chr4 500 789   0
```

I found the answer to match the files and output a new file at the same forum:

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$1,$2,$3]){print b}}' file1 file2`

But I want to include the match and mismatch score column in the output file too.

Answer (score 0):

### *script*

```
#!/bin/bash
filea=$1
fileb=$2
fout=$3
sed -i "/^$/d" $filea $fileb
cat $filea | while read a b c
  do
    grep "$a.*$b.*$c" $fileb &>/dev/null && l="$a   $b  $c  1" || l="$a $b  $c  0"
    grep "$l" $fout &>/dev/null || echo "$l" >> $fout
  done
cat $fileb | while read a b c
  do
    grep "$a.*$b.*$c" $filea $fout &>/dev/null && l="$a $b  $c  1" || l="$a $b  $c  0"
    grep "$l" $fout &>/dev/null || echo "$l" >> $fout
  done
```

### *stdout*

```
younes@cbfcdf:~$ cat filea
chr1 899 1098
chr3 677 900
chr3 844 1045
younes@cbfcdf:~$ cat fileb
chr3 844 1045
chr1 899 1098
chr4 500 789
younes@cbfcdf:~$ ./script filea fileb new_file
younes@cbfcdf:~$ cat new_file 
chr1    899     1098    1
chr3    677     900     0
chr3    844     1045    1
chr4    500     789     0
younes@cbfcdf:~$
```